# Expected value of travelled distance

Tags: probability, expected-value

A playground is a square with side length 10. A robot is in the center of the playground. The robot can go up, down ,left or right.(But not at the same time.) Suppose the center of the playground is the origin. The robot wants to go to (x,y). Let D be total distance traveled in order to reach (x,y). What is the expected value of D?

Comment: Does the robot travel in two line segments, one $|x|$ and the other |y|$?

Comment: If (in effect) there is a homing beacon so the robot never takes a mis-step then obviously, the answer is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  I'm guessing that that does not represent the OP's intent.  I'm guessing that the OP intends that the robot makes *totally random moves* forever (always staying within the confines of the playground) until grid point $(x,y)$ is reached.  Here, I am assuming that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}.$  Personally, I don't know how to attack the problem that I *suspect* that the OP is asking.

Comment: So the robot moves randomly in 4 directions, until it reaches a single point $(x,y)$?

Comment: @peterwhy surely you realize that the more clarity with which a problem is presented, the less (*artistry*) will be involved in its solution.

Comment: The question I have is what have you tried? Have you tried to find the probability of it ever reaching that point? That may give you some insight into how to set up expected number of steps.

Comment: @MathLover Normally, I would regard your comment as very reasonable.  In this case, I don't because if I was atacking this problem, I would immediately recognize that my probability/statistics training/intuition (**so far**) is inadequate.  Therefore, my **first try** would *have to be* searching for the appropriate probability/statistics text book (or online pdf), going to **page 1**, and attacking the text.  As I see it, the real issue is therefore: What is the probability/statistics-training **background** of the OP and **how** did the OP happen to be confronted with this problem?